# libpcap equivalent for Windows C++

Tags: windows, c++, packet-capture

I am working on a cross-platform C++ application which has to save packets from another system into pcap file. In Ubuntu, I was able to use libpcap for the same. I am looking for a cross-platform library / libpcap equivalent for Windows to implement the same.

Alternatives I found:

- npcap - It has restriction on commercial usage. I prefer the ones that can be freely distributed.
- winpcap - depracated.
- Raw C++ sniffing - Couldn't find a way to save to pcap.